# PHP stop foreach()

Tags: php, count, foreach

There is a variable `$posts`, which gives an array with many values.

`foreach()` is used for output:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    ...
}
```

How to show only five first values from `$posts`?

Like, if we have 100 values, it should give just five.

Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use either [`array_slice():`](http://php.net/array_slice)

```
foreach (array_slice($posts, 0, 5) as $post)
....
```

or a counter variable and `break`:

```
$counter = 0;

foreach ($posts as $post)
 { .....

   if ($counter >= 5) 
    break;

   $counter++;
    }
```

Answer (score 17):

This should work:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($posts as $post) { 
  if(++$i > 5)
    break;
  ... 
}
```